# Selenium - Gherkin - Java: verifying text on a mandatory field

Tags: java, selenium, bdd, gherkin

Short Version: I have a mandatory field, the element which displays the "this field is mandatory" can contain more than one message. I'm struggling to set up my BDD feature step, page & step file to verify the correct message is being displayed.

Long version:
Relatively new to Java/Selenium and new to this form of BDD Automation testing, but I was handed this framework and are chugging along. I've added a step to a scenario as there was a couple of fields which were minatory but this was not being tested.

The site this is for in development which will have 20+ regional versions for it  so I've tried to keep any hard cording to a minimum/

**The Scenario**

```
Scenario: 'Do you want to Join an Existing Company?' is an optional radio button selection field which displays 'Company Account Number' and 'Company Name' fields if the 'Yes' option is selected and is defaulted to option 'No'
Given The user is on the Lite Registration page
Than The 'Do you want to Join an Existing Company' radio button selection field is displayed
And the default selection is 'No'
And 'Company Account Number' and 'Company Name' fields are displayed for selection 'Yes'
And A 'Join request' message is displayed for a selection of 'Yes'
And 'Company Account Number' is a numeric field with max 30 char
And 'Company Name' is an alphanumeric filed with max 60 char
And 'Company Account Number' and 'Company Name' are mandatory fields <-- My new step
```

The issue is the element which contains the error message (which is 'This field is required.') also displays other messages so I can't just confirm the element with the error is being displayed.

I've been trying to do something with asserts and the .getText command for that element but I either passes when it shouldn't or the step gets ignored with an Assertion error.

The relevant parts of the Pagefile

```
@FindBy(css = "#accountNumber-error")
private WebElement JECAccountNumberCharError;


//Methods


public boolean Try1() {

    String m = JECAccountNumberCharError.getText();
    return m.equals("This field is required");
} here
```

The relevant parts of the Step file

```
 @And("^'Company Account Number' and 'Company Name' are mandatory fields$")
public void companyAccountNumberAndCompanyNameAreMandatoryFields() throws Throwable {
    Assert.assertTrue(liteRegistration_page.Try1());
}
```

in the above case, the test is ignored with an assertion error in the output

```
> java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52) 
at steps.registration.LiteRegistration_Steps.companyAccountNumberAndCompanyNameAreMandatoryFields(LiteRegistration_Steps.java:481)
at ✽.And 'Company Account Number' and 'Company Name' are mandatory fields(Registration/LiteRegistration_FeildValidation.feature:78)
```

I'm I barking up the wrong tree with the solution I'm going for? I'll really appreciate you peeps help

edit: HTML for the element

```
<div class="label-floating form-group error-group">
                    <label for="accountNumber" class="control-label">Company account number</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control error" name="account.accountNumber" id="accountNumber" value="" aria-invalid="true" required=""><label id="accountNumber-error" class="error" for="accountNumber">This field is required.</label>

                    <input type="hidden" id="accountNumberInexistent" value="This account number does not exist">
                </div>
```

Comment: Can you share html of the fields? Is the mandatory check done by html5? Can you get message text with getText?

Comment: @sers That's what Im trying to do, using .getText on the element with the text and checking against  the message which is being displayed.

My current fudge is to put in valid inputs for the other fields and then checking the Submit button is still disabled.

Comment: <div class="label-floating form-group error-group">
                        <label for="accountNumber" class="control-label">Company account number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control error" name="account.accountNumber" id="accountNumber" value="" aria-invalid="true" required=""><label id="accountNumber-error" class="error" for="accountNumber">This field is required.</label>
                        
                        <input type="hidden" id="accountNumberInexistent" value="This account number does not exist">
                    </div>

Comment: Check and share value of `String validationMessage = driver.findElement(By.id("accountNumber")).getAttribute("validationMessage");`

Comment: Where would I put that line ?

Comment: Put it to try1 as first line and print result or debug. Or open the page, open chrome devtool -> console tab and put document.querySelector("#accountNumber").getAttribute("validationMessage");